Why can't I change the compiler version in Codesys?
I hope to change the compiler version. According to official information, I should be able to select the version I want in this dialog box, but as shown in the screenshot, the drop-down box is disabled.
thanks for your help.
screenshot
official information
What I've tried:
I tried it in the following versions of Codesys and couldn't select the compiler version.
Codesys versions:
3.5 SP20
3.5 SP19
3.5 SP19 Patch7
What I expecting:
Can change compiler version.

Have you checked that you have more than one compiler version available?  Looking at my environment, I only see 2 in the drop down, and the older one results from a previous version from which I upgraded.  I assume it is not automatic that you get access to all past versions, they must be installed to be available.
